# Changing Wordpress template for specific product category page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wpml

I'm trying to change the template of a specific product category page, but I can't for the life of me get it to work. I've tried taxonomy-product_cat-the-category but to no avail. I'm using wpml with the categories in 3 different languages if that makes a difference. I've tried with the slugs of each of the 3 langauges but still doesn't work. Don't understand what could be causing this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First copy `taxonomy-product_cat.php` & `archive-product.php` from WooCommerce Plugin directory - `wordpress\wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\templates` to your theme - `wordpress\wp-content\themes\your-theme\woocommerce`.

Then make copy of `archive-product.php` files in your theme's woocommerce directory like `archive-product-2.php`, `archive-product-3.php` etc. Later you are going to modify these files as per your category.

Then open `taxonomy-product_cat.php` file. The code will look like below one.

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

wc_get_template( 'archive-product.php' );
```

We need to modify the template call `wc_get_template()` in this code with our conditions.

First get the current category slug & then we can compare the slug. As per the slug, we will call different archive product files.

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

// Get current category slug
global $wp_query;
$cat_slug = $wp_query->query_vars['product_cat'];

// Call template conditionally
if($cat_slug == 'accessories') {
    wc_get_template( 'archive-product-2.php' );
} else  {
    wc_get_template( 'archive-product.php' );   
}
```

**Updates**

In my experience, the best approach is avoid WooCommerce template overriding by copying in to theme files. The WooCommerce have regular updates on the templates and it is better to update templates on each time to avoid future issues. So if possible, maximum use filter hooks other than template overriding.

Answer (score -2):

You can can't change the template of WP for a specific category but

- For only overriding design: You can do css by using **body.term-yourcategoryname** at starting of each class, ID or tag name like this:

  body.term-car h1 {
     color: red;
     font-size: 22px;
  }
- For enhancing Layout: or add some new feature you can use wooommerce default functions like: **$term->name;** in archive-product.php in your child theme.

**example:**

```
if($term->name == "car") {
   // your code will goes here
}
```

Comment: "You can can't change the template of WP for a specific category" that is incorrect. See [the WordPress template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/).

Comment: haha you didn't even got my point i was talking about for WP theme like you can't set WP theme for only specific category or custom page etc.

Comment: @Harry, Template for taxonomy term is possible by following WordPress template hierarchy. But WooCommerce have its own template structure & so we have to follow that structure to override WooCommerce templates.